# Java Cache Query Results

Tags: java, database, caching, out-of-memory

I am using JDBC. I have database intensive computations, and I would like to cache the results.

I am using `HashMap<String, ResultSet>` to cache the results. However, the program often gives OutOfMemory Exception because the cache gets too large.

Any advice about a better data structure/caching interface to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't cache the `ResultSet`, create some domain objects with the data and then cache them.

Second, use some kind of caching framework that evicts old entries that are not used. My favorite is [Guava Cache](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained) for it's easy configuration in code, but another popular one is [Ehcache](http://ehcache.org/).

Comment: Thanks, will look into them.